# Find the radius of circle in PostGIS using query in php?

Tags: php, database, postgis, geometry

I have the geometry type defined for the polygons and circle in PostGIS and now I need to find the radius of the circle in this geometry type??
I have found the centre by using
    ST_X(ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(shape))) AS lat,
    ST_Y(ST_ASTEXT(ST_CENTROID(shape))) as lgt,
Can anyone help me to get the radius ??

Comment: You don't need to call ST_AsText here, as ST_X/ST_Y will return a number (float) anyway. D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ST_Envelope](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) function to get the bounding box of any polygon (not just a circle). You can then use the [ST_XMin](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_XMin.html), [ST_YMin](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_YMin.html), [ST_XMax](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_XMax.html) and [ST_YMax](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_YMax.html) functions to extract the width and height. As it is a circle, you could use either, so something like:

```
SELECT (ST_XMax(bbox)-ST_XMin(bbox))/2 as radius
FROM 
  (SELECT ST_Envelope(shape) as bbox from sometable) env
```

where the sub-query is just shorthand to avoid having to call ST_Envelope twice, but you could also write,

```
SELECT (ST_XMax(ST_Envelope(shape)) - ST_XMin(ST_Envelope(shape)))/2 as radius
FROM sometable
```

which seems shorter, but, is I feel less elegant, and would be longer if you wanted the height. The query optimizer will view them as the same query, either way.